# Launch custom EXE from Chrome link

Tags: asp.net, windows, google-chrome

For an intranet app running on Windows 7, we need to create links that launch an EXE from Chrome. The link will look like this:

```
myapp://filename.xyz?param1=abcd&param2=efgh
```

This would launch myapp.exe and let it receive the parameters and launch the another custom app associated with the file on the user's machine.

In other words, how can we build something like the iTunes app that is launched from the browser? We're using C# 4.5 to build this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your application as a protocol Handler:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx